# Pages stuck connecting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

Our internet has been acting very strange as of late.

Especially during evening/night when the browser is trying to load pages, it'll report back "Connecting..." on and off and then timeout as a result. Some pages, such as Google, are still able to load fine (sometimes). Initially, I thought this was a problem with the DNS on the router seeing as this was occurring for my girlfriend at the same time. However, none of the error codes returned indicated that the lookup failed.

The next day I went out and got a Google Wifi mesh system, and oddly the same thing started occurring around nighttime. Luckily Google Wifi can run a speed test directly on the router. This test resulted in either failing, saying it couldn't connect to the internet, or at a speed of 0/0.

I spoke to the broadband company this morning, and told me that everything looked fine on their end.

At this point, I'm at my wit's end. I'm not sure where the issue lies other than the fiber box installed directly connected to your router.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you connect a Laptop directly to the ISP entrance to your residence?  That is what I do. I do this when Internet is acting up and I know right away whether the problem is my network or the ISP.

Comment: while the computer fail to load some specific pages, can it connect to the Internet?

Comment: Networking isn't my strong suit. It's usually only a problem for 30 seconds, so it's tough to just plug in a laptop, it'll most likely be too late. 
@GloriaGu I can have a conversation on Discord meanwhile it's refusing to connect :)

Comment: Try opening up a command prompt and typing in `ping 8.8.8.8 -t` and hit enter.  Keep that page open and running in the background, then when you experience the issues, take a look and see what your pings look like.

Comment: If the issue is bandwidth/sudden influx of demand, you'll typically see intermittent entries showing `Request timed out` sprinkled in.  This can also happen in very rare cases if you have multiple network interfaces, e.g., ethernet & wireless profiles configured.  A small percentage of users have issues where, even when correctly disabled, the system still incorrectly switches between network adapters on the backend causing intermittent connection.

Comment: @Arctiic doesn't look like it's the case. Ping is steady around 16-19 ms meanwhile chrome is just reporting "Connecting..." when I open a page I haven't visited _recently_ It's almost like some sort of lookup is going wrong, but it's not reporting a DNS error, just "err_connection_timed_out" :/

Comment: Are you certain `dr.dk` resolves correctly from your DNS settings?  Trying `ping dr.dk -a -t`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say from experience that this is most likely due to `wuauserv` from the symptoms you're describing.  Note that even when you have *Active Hours* configured, I've commonly observed the service running irregardless to time scoping.  We have T2 at my office, so every time this happens, the fileserver gets throttled and every domain workstation starts acting funky.  We were able to confirm when we called the ISP and a technician (make sure you get someone higher than wave 1) was able to confirm traffic to/from one of Microsoft's known servers addresses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it looks like `wuaserv` isn't even running :(

Comment: I wouldn't put it past Microsoft.  The only way to definitively rule it out would be to 1) use software, e.g., WireShark to examine your network traffic, or if you're not too network savvy, then 2) restart in safe-mode *or* local admin account with networking disabled, and see if you can reproduce the issue.  Note that in some model routers, network traffic logging might be available to view from your router's web interface.